# change image in a picturebox on scroll in C++/CLI

Tags: scroll, c++-cli

I have a form application in C++ CLI. It has a scroll bar. I have a panel inside form and a number of picture boxes in it. The panel has auto scroll set. Is it possible that I can hide the panel auto scroll bar and control its scrolling by the form scroll bar.
 The form screen shot is attached here

[image: my_form_with_panel]

I tried changing the VerticalScroll.Visible property of the panel. But it doesn't help.

regards,
Rohini

Comment: Set the panel's AutoSize property to True so it will automatically grow when you add too many boxes.  Set the form's AutoScroll to True so it automatically displays the scrollbar, don't use your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..This solution works for the sample above app, but in our actual application the number picturebx can be too large so that the panel height exceeds its limit https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/de57df15-c633-4898-8665-c720428a8940/systemwindowsformspanel-maximum-size-width-and-height-?forum=winforms. That's why we opted for customising the scroll operation.

Comment: You can apply scroll to width too. Width and height are often communicated to windows via a message's LPARAM (which is 32-bit) the low-order 16 bits is the width and the high-order is the height.  Depending on what particular property you're tyring to affect, the lowest-common-denominator may be that it will be communicated this way, limited the nb of bits of precision dramatically.  See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646(VS.85).aspx